# Tkinter window hangs after restoring from system tray (using pystray)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a Tkinter-based GUI in Python. I would like the window to hide to system tray when it is minimized (using `pystray` module). It hides, but it only appears on the screen and hangs, when I'm trying to restore it.

Here's what I have tried:

```
from tkinter import *

from PIL import Image
import pystray


def hide_to_tray(_event=None):
    tray_icon = pystray.Icon("MyTrayIcon", title="My tray icon")  # create the tray icon
    tray_icon.icon = Image.open("app_icon.ico")  # open the icon using PIL
    tray_icon.menu = pystray.Menu(pystray.MenuItem("Open", lambda: tray_icon.stop(), default=True))  # create the menu
    root.withdraw()  # hide the window
    tray_icon.run()  # run the icon's main loop
    # icon mainloop
    root.deiconify()  # when the icon mainloop had been stopped, show the window again
    root.focus_force()  # focus on it

root = Tk()
btn = Button(root, text="Sample button")
btn.grid()
root.bind("<Unmap>", hide_to_tray)  # hide to tray on minimizing
root.mainloop()
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Use [infi.systray](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.systray)

It runs on a seperate thread and thus won't block, install it with pip:

```
pip install infi.systray
```

#### Don't call tkinter methods from the `info.systray` thread:

Since `infi.systray` runs on a seperate thread, you mustn't call tkinter methods directly in the callback functions that you pass to the systray icon on creation. Use a thread safe way (e.g. [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)) to inform the main thread about events in the systray icon instead!

### 2. Don't run `pystray` and `tkinter` at the same time

You can't run them both because they block the running thread and both have to run on the mainthread.
See [Osher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54841035) that only displays the system tray icon when the tkinter app is closed.

Comment: There is anyway to run tkinter or pystray in another thread outside the main thread and than communicate each other with queue?

Comment: I think both pystray and tkinter only work if run on the main thread, sadly