# Start Python script GUI minimized / in Windows Tray | Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pystray

I´ve built a simple GUI app, and I´m playing with `pystray`.
Actually, my script starts as usual, the first thing you see is the GUI.
If you klick on exit, the GUI minimize, and the tray Icon spawns.

For now, i search a way to start my script in this "tray Mode"
here are some informations:

```
class Hauptfenster:

    # Define a function for quit the window
    def quit_window(icon, item):
        icon.stop()
        fenster.destroy()

    # Define a function to show the window again
    def show_window(icon, item):
        icon.stop()
        fenster.after(0, fenster.deiconify())

    # Hide the window and show on the system taskbar
    @staticmethod
    def hide_window():
        fenster.withdraw()
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(application_path, iconFile))
        menu = (item('Beenden', Frontend.Hauptfenster.quit_window), item('Einstellungen', Frontend.Hauptfenster.show_window))
        icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "Quicksafe", menu)
        icon.run()
```

Please ask me if you need some more Information and Thanks a lot !
Best regards

Background:
My programm should lay in the autostart of win10 , but i dont want to minimize the window each time i restart my pc

Comment: [Are you looking for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54841035/13629335)

Comment: @Atlas435Not at all... pystray works fine... but i want to start my programm in this "Tray Mode" from theb beginning

Comment: since I dont use this modul I cant provide code. But Im not quit sure why it shouldnt be possible to call the functions you like in the `__init__` section of your code, that will be executed as soon as you run this code. What am I missing ?

Comment: @iWischMob You might want to use pythonw.exe. Not sure tho, but for further information, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe/30313091)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added my method `hide_window` to my main function,
when script starts, you see something moving on to screen for 2ms.. but it disapears very quick... so thats something I can live with