# With Python/pystray, how to maximize a window from the system tray icon by clicking it?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, system-tray, pystray

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54835399/running-a-tkinter-window-and-pystray-icon-together), I've implemented to minimize the window of a app to system tray.

However, i don't figured out how to restore the window by clicking in the system's tray icon.
Only opening the menu and choosing 'show' optin this is possible.
Clicking at the icon, a TypeError raises:

```
File "C:\<path>\pystray\_base.py", line 106, in __call__
self._menu(self)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Any hint for me?
Thanks

Comment: it is telling you that `self._menu` is a tuple and you can't obviously call a tuple, so for example `self._menu = (1, 2, 3)` and you attempt to do `(1, 2, 3)()`

Comment: I see.
However the right-click over the icon works for show the menu, but the left-click doesn't.
In the code, the 'menu' variable is defined as a tuple with the options of the menu.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the `menu` option an instance of `pystray.Menu` instead of passing a tuple:

```py
...
from pystray import Menu, MenuItem, Icon
...
def withdraw_window():  
    window.withdraw()
    image = Image.open("icon.png")
    # create instance of pystray.Menu instead of a tuple
    menu = Menu(
        MenuItem('Quit', quit_window),
        MenuItem('Show', show_window, default=True) # set 'Show' as the default action
    )
    icon = Icon("name", icon=image, title="title", menu=menu)
    icon.run()
...
```